# how to store json response value into edittext in android

Tags: php, android, json

Hi In this getting reg_no array value coming from database I want display that value into `EditText` without clicking any button.

Can any one please help me how to display the `EditText` value
**class file**

```
 String RegNo = DatabaseUtility.executeQueryPhp("reg","");
        System.out.print(RegNo);
        try
        {
            JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(RegNo);
            reg_no = new String[JA.length()];
            for(int i=0;i<JA.length();i++)
            {
                reg_no[i] = JA.getJSONObject(i).getString("reg_no");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do something like this :

```
String value = "";
    for(int i=0;i<JA.length();i++)
                {

                    reg_no[i] = JA.getJSONObject(i).getString("reg_no");
                    value+=reg_no[i];
                }

 myEditText.setText(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

For showing every single value in new `EditText`

```
for(int i=0;i<JA.length();i++)
  {
    reg_no[i] = JA.getJSONObject(i).getString("reg_no");
    EditText edit = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
    edit.setText(reg_no[i]);

  }
```

Showing All Values in Single `EditText`

```
EditText edit = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
for(int i=0;i<JA.length();i++)
      {
        reg_no[i] = JA.getJSONObject(i).getString("reg_no");   
        edit.append(reg_no[i]);

      }
```

Comment: How to append PAT to reg_no

Comment: What is PAT? m not getting

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
for (int i = 0; i < JA.length(); i++) 
 {
    JSONObject jsonObject = JA.getJSONObject(i);

    reg_no[i] = jsonObject.getInt("reg_no");
    editText[i].setText(reg_no[i].toString);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `StringBuilder` class

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String RegNo = DatabaseUtility.executeQueryPhp("reg","");
    System.out.print(RegNo);
    try
    {
        JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(RegNo);
        reg_no = new String[JA.length()];
        for(int i=0;i<JA.length();i++)
        {
            reg_no[i] = JA.getJSONObject(i).getString("reg_no");
            sb.append(reg_no[i]); 
        }

        myEditText.setText(sb.toString());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
    }
```